# Is XML one of the most widely-used formats for sharing structured information?

Tags: programming

W3C [claims that](http://www.w3.org/standards/xml/core)

> XML is one of the most widely-used formats for sharing structured information today

Does anyone know if there is any corroborating evidence (studies, reviews, etc.) for this statement?

Comment: I guess it's a fair question... Although for me personally, it's  in the "the sky is blue" category and doesn't need proving :)

Comment: I'd accuse XML of being the most-widely-used-in-the-wrong-places format going these days. I must now go dunk my head in a bucket of iced brine to cool my hatred of overapplied buzztechnologies.

Comment: W3C's claim that XML is ***one of*** the most widely-used formats for sharing structured information is indisputable. But your title asks whether it's ***the*** most widely-used format. W3C isn't claiming it is...

Comment: @ArmenTsirunyan: Oops. My bad. Fixed.

Comment: Voting to close for the reason Armen gave.

Comment: @Sklivvz Ant build files are also xml

Comment: @SonnyOrdell Sorry I've had to reopen after reading [this](http://meta.skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/1406/if-a-claim-is-commonly-accepted-does-questioning-it-require-a-notable-counter-c). It unfortunately erased your close vote.

Comment: @Sklivvz I missed what happened..., was the question closed, and then reopened? Is that answer to the question on meta now policy?

Comment: Also my close vote is still there. It may have erased someone else's close vote.

Answer (score 9):

From [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XML)

> RSS, Atom, SOAP, and XHTML are all XML. XML-based formats have become
>   the default for many office-productivity tools, including Microsoft
>   Office (Office Open XML), OpenOffice.org (OpenDocument), and Apple's
>   iWork. XML has also been employed as the base language for
>   communication protocols, such as XMPP.

XBRL is now the global standard for exchanging business information - used for tax filing, regulators, stock exchanges etc.

DocBook, ePUB, GraphML and MathML, OpenDocument, SAML and many others are all XML formats.

So to answer the "is it one of the most widely used formats" - absolutely. From the evidence I have available it appears to be **the** most widely used, but I don't have enough information to categorically state that.

Comment: Exchanges communicate using FIXML as well

Comment: SVG (Scalable Vector Graphics) are also stored in XML format. The media type is `image/svg+xml`